# Android Studio - Transparent Action Bar - Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, themes, transparent, android-theme

I have a navigation drawer template. I have modified the action bar so I don't see the title. And I know how to change the colors, but I do not know how to get this effect:

[image]

This is my current status:

[image]

This is my styles.xml (what teme I'm using):

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Toolbar` with transparent background.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#4BAE4F"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Place your content here-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    }
}
```

**styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

From API 19 you can set parameter `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` in your `styles.xml` to make status bar transparent as well.

Comment: I tried but the app keeps crashing. Is there another way to get this effect, or do I have to restart the entire app ?

Comment: check out logcat output to know the reason of the crash. Also make sure you set the parent of your AppTheme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.